# ECL - showing differences results for debugging

Tags: eclipse, model, compare, metamodel, epsilon

i'm using Epsilon Comparison Language for the first time. I am writing a code in order to compare two models, in particular i want to show some information on the default output stream console when the code finds differences between the models. I want to visualize, for example, the name of the involved rule and the differences between the fields under investigation. When the comparison ends without differences i can visualize, for example, all that i need using the matchInfo variable in a "do" block. How can i solve the problem when the code find some differences? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ECL does not provide any built-in differencing or difference visualisation capabilities. If you need such capabilities my suggestion would be to consider using [EMFCompare](https://www.eclipse.org/emf/compare/).

Comment: I'm solving the problem described in my previous question adding a "not" after the "compare", so i can add information in the info variable when i find differences. Now i have another problem: following this solution i have to write a lot of rules, but i have read that is impossible to invoke the match operation more times on the same element. Do you know how to use the match operation on the same elemente more than once? (i want to invoke it, for example, for every field of an element).